# How to find only original tracks on soundcloud

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am using soundcloud API for a project but the problem is I get remix of the original songs or cover version, its okay if I get remix and cover version but is there any mechanism that the original one comes as first song in the search result ? I tried searching on Google and read the API documentation but found nothing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The track object in soundcloud's API actually has the [`track_type`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#track_type) property which has possible values of 'original' and 'remix' among other things. Sadly like most valueable metadata the track object has, content providers neglect to fill the field. So unless content providers start putting more effort into filling in the metadata fields the only option you have is giving songs priority based on words in the title or tags.